# Book/notes on Real Analytic Functions.

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, real-algebraic-geometry

I am currently working with Real Algebraic Geometry, and I'm needing references for Real Analytic Functions but I'm having a hard time finding them. Does anyone know a good book/set of notes on the subject?

Answer (score 2):

You might try *A Primer of Real Analytic Functions*, by  Steven G. Krantz and Harold R. Parks.